# End the while loop in the string token

Tags: c++

how can I end the while loop inside the getToken

```
 int i =0;  //need to be gobal variable because when we use getToken
 next time
            //it should be not zero


char* getToken(const char* text, char end)
{

    char* charPtr = new char[maxWordLength];

    int charCount =0;
    if (text[i] == ' ') {
        i++;
    }
    else if(text[i] == '\0')  //not sure if it's used
        return 0;
    while (text[i] != end)  //content *text point to is not space
    {
        if ('!'<= text[i]&& text[i]<='~') //fromASCII table 33~126 not include space
        {
            charPtr[charCount++]= text[i++];

        }

    }
    charPtr[charCount] = '\0';
    return charPtr;
}
```

this is from the main()

```
char input[28] = "hi ok it's me?? no!! ";
cout << getToken(input,' ')<<" ";
cout <<endl;
cout << getToken(input,' ')<<" ";
cout <<endl;
cout << getToken(input,' ')<<" ";
cout << getToken(input,' ')<<" ";
cout << getToken(input,' ')<<" ";
```

when I put the next cout << getToken(input,' ')<<" ";

the loop will run forever ...

thanks

//////////////////////add 2014 10 27

if I want to reuse the value in the struct

```
struct subString subStr[NumberOfSubstr];

struct subString
{

    int numberOfSub = 0;
    char data[maxWordLength];

};
```

After I manipulate subStr[i] and store the data in the struct and number
How can I reuse this data.

/////////////using for output token////////////////////

```
 struct GetToken tokenObject;
    struct subString subStr[NumberOfSubstr];
    for (int i=0; i<6; ++i) {
        char *substring2 =subStr[i].data;
        substring2= tokenObject.getToken(ptr, ' ');
        cout <<substring2<<" ";

    }
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
But After I use next function like the one downward to call the struct,
I found the value in the struct is all gone.

```
for (int i=1; i<6; ++i) {

            char *substring0 = subStr[0].data;
            char *key = keyword;
            if ( easyMatch(substring0, key)>=0) //substring
                subStr[0].numberOfSub++; //for first 1
            char *substring = subStr[i].data;
            int keyLen = size(key);
            int subLen = size(substring);
            if(keyLen<subLen) // not total match maybe substring

            {
                //for second to the last
                //if string j match early string
                //number of early string ++
                //in the end of loop
                //if string is not match but is substring
                //numberof substring ++
                for(int j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
                {
                    char*subBefore =subStr[j].data;
                    char*subNow = subStr[i].data;
                    int subBeforeLen = size(subBefore);
                    int subNowLen = size(subNow);
                if (subBeforeLen == subNowLen &&easyMatch(subBefore, subNow))
                    subStr[j].numberOfSub++;
                }//end for

                char*subNow = subStr[i].data;
                if (easyMatch(subNow, keyword)>0) //new found substring
                    subStr[i].numberOfSub++;

            }//end if
        }//end outer for
```

How can I reuse the data in the struct or do I need to use another array to save it

Since every string in the struct has an related number, I want it to be linked together.

thanks a lot

Comment: What did you notice stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: I don't even get the expected output from this code..

Comment: if I don't add the last cout It's ok it print all the stuff i want    but if i add it the program will not stop and it only shows the first two tokens

Comment: What's the end goal ? What are you trying to achieve with `input` ?

Comment: I want to print every token then compare it with some keyword

Comment: @ShawnTsai Show the expected output for your `hi ok it's me?? no!! ` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop:

```
while (text[i] != end)  //content *text point to is not space
{
    if ('!'<= text[i]&& text[i]<='~') //fromASCII table 33~126 not include space
    {
        charPtr[charCount++]= text[i++];

    }

}
```

will not end when you reach the end of the input string, since that is a zero-value, which is outside the "ascii table" values that you accept. So the loop will just sit there and spin until you get bored and stop it.

The solution is to identify the end of the string (or it's length). I would do this:

```
while (text[i] && text[i] != end)  //content *text point to is not space 
                                   // and not end of string
{
   ... 
}
```

By the way, your code is leaking memory, you need to do:

```
tmp = getToken(input, ' ');
cout << tmp << " ";
delete [] tmp;
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I have a question more. how can I get rid of the
global variable i and still keep the function of Ptr which could point to the specific location next time.
If I want to use this function next times, how can I modify the value of i.    thank you

Comment: Several ways are possible: two obvious ones are to pass the variable in by reference, or make a class that does the token-parsing of a string, and has a member function to give you each token.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I end the while loop

`break` keyword does it.